# Xgboost cox survival time entry

Tags: xgboost, survival, cox

In the new implementation of cox ph survival model in xgboost 0.81 how does one specify  start and end time of an event?

Thanks

The R equivalent function would be for example :

```r
cph_mod = coxph(Surv(Start, Stop, Status) ~ Age + Sex + SBP, data=data)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XGBoost do not allow for start (i.e. delayed entry). If it makes sense for the application, you can always change the underlying time scale so all subjects start at *time=0*. However, XGBoost does allow for right censored data. It seems impossible to find any documentation/example for how to implement a Cox model, but from the source code you can read ["Cox regression for censored survival data (negative labels are considered censored)."](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/objective/regression_obj.cu#L276)

Here is a short example for anyone who want to try XGBoost with **obj="survival:cox"**. We can compare the results to to the scikit-learn survival package **sksurv**. To make XGBoost more similar to that framework we use a linear booster instead of a tree booster.

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from sksurv.datasets import load_aids
from sksurv.linear_model import CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis

# load and inspect the data
data_x, data_y = load_aids()
data_y[10:15]
Out[586]: 
array([(False, 334.), (False, 285.), (False, 265.), ( True, 206.),
   (False, 305.)], dtype=[('censor', '?'), ('time', '<f8')])

# Since XGBoost only allow one column for y, the censoring information
# is coded as negative values:
data_y_xgb = [x[1] if x[0] else -x[1] for x in data_y]
data_y_xgb[10:15]
Out[3]: [-334.0, -285.0, -265.0, 206.0, -305.0]

data_x = data_x[['age', 'cd4']]
data_x.head()
Out[4]: 
    age    cd4
0  34.0  169.0
1  34.0  149.5
2  20.0   23.5
3  48.0   46.0
4  46.0   10.0

# Since sksurv output log hazard ratios (here relative to 0 on predictors)
# we must use 'output_margin=True' for comparability.
estimator = CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis().fit(data_x, data_y)
gbm = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='survival:cox',
                       booster='gblinear',
                       base_score=1,
                       n_estimators=1000).fit(data_x, data_y_xgb)
prediction_sksurv = estimator.predict(data_x)
predictions_xgb = gbm.predict(data_x, output_margin=True)
d = pd.DataFrame({'xgb': predictions_xgb,
                  'sksurv': prediction_sksurv})
d.head()
Out[13]: 
     sksurv       xgb
0 -1.892490 -1.843828
1 -1.569389 -1.524385
2  0.144572  0.207866
3  0.519293  0.502953
4  1.062392  1.045287

d.plot.scatter('xgb', 'sksurv')
```

[image]

Note that these are predictions on the same data that was use to fit the model. It seems that XGBoost get the values right but sometimes with a linear transformation. I do not know why. Play around with *base_score* and *n_estimators*. Perhaps someone can add to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alternatively I could use the grouping in a Dmatrix, but I don't think it is handled for cox ph as of yet.